# Decorators for Instance Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Wrapping a class's method in a "boilerplate" Python decorator will treat that method as a regular function and make it lose its `__self__` attribute that refers to the class instance object.  Can this be avoided?

Take the following class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def meth(self):
        pass
```

If `meth()` is undecorated, `MyClass().meth.__self__` refers to an instance method and enables something like `setattr(my_class_object.meth.__self__, 'a', 5)`.

But when wrapping anything in a decorator, only the function object is passed; the object to which it is actually bound is not passed on along with it.  (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105234/7954504) answer.)

```
import functools

def decorate(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do something to method.__self__ such as setattr
        print(hasattr(method, '__self__'))
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @decorate
    def meth(self):
        pass

MyClass().meth()
# False            <--------
```

Can this be overriden?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. Why do you want to access the `__self__` attribute? Why don't you just add `self` as the first parameter of `wrapper`?

Comment: why you cannot do `setattr(args[0], 'a', 5)`? `args[0]` on method is `self`

Comment: @Aran-Fey I suspected someone would say that ...  An example: use a decorator to update a class attribute that is a log of method calls and their parameters.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ah, duh.  I think that should work here

Comment: @BradSolomon I write and answer then :)

Comment: Does it really make sense? Using `args[0]` instead of `def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):`? What is the difference?

Comment: @Sraw `self` has clearer intent so `args[0]` should be avoided in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decorate method of the class, first argument is always `self` object (you can access it with `args[0]`):

```
import functools

def decorate(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(hasattr(args[0], 'a'))
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @decorate
    def meth(self):
        pass

MyClass().meth()
```

Prints:

```
True
```

**Edit:**

You can specify also `self` in your `wrapper` function (based on comments):

```
import functools

def decorate(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(hasattr(self, 'a'))
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @decorate
    def meth(self):
        pass

MyClass().meth()
```

Prints also:

```
True
```

Comment: Why do we have to use @functools.wraps(method)?

Answer (score 5):

Your main misunderstanding here is order of operation.

When the `decorate()` decorator is called, `meth()` is not a method yet - it is still a function - it is only when the `class` block is over that `meth` is transformed into a method by the metaclass descriptors! - that's why it doesn't have `__self__` (yet).

In other words, to decorate methods you have to ignore the fact that they are methods and treat them as normal functions - because that's what they are when the decorator is called.

In fact, the original `meth` function will never turn into a method - instead the function `wrapper` you returned from the decorator will be part of the class and will be the one that will get the `__self__` attribute later.

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify the process of decorating:

When you decorate `meth` with `decorate` in class `MyClass`, you are doing:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ... omit
    meth = decorate(meth)  # the meth in "()" is the original function.
```

As you can see, `decorate` takes `method` which is a function as parameter and return `wrapper` which is another funtion. And now the original `meth` in `MyClass` is replaced by new one `wrapper`. So when you call `myclass_instance.meth()`, you are calling the new `wrapper` function.

There isn't any black magic, so `self` can be definitely passed into `wrapper`, and it is safe to accept `self` using `wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)`.